# listview keeps getting doubled everytime the activity is loaded.

Tags: android, android-listview

listview keeps getting doubled (populated everytime with previous data making the data appear twice) everytime the activity is loaded

```
public class FragmentActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    private ListView discrepancy_list;
    private DiscrepancyListAdapter list_adapter = null;
    private ArrayList<CommonEntity> discrepancyList = new ArrayList<CommonEntity>();
    private RelativeLayout objRelativeLayout;
    private static int X_CO_ordinate;
    private static int Y_CO_ordinate;
    private ArrayList<String> arrlstCo_ordinate;
    private ArrayList<String> arrlst_Count;
    private boolean touch = true,isOnLaunch = false;
    private int editText_ID=1,count=1;
    private EditText objEditText;
    private SortedMap<Integer,String> mapDefect=null;
    private int final_position; 
    private ImageButton objImageButton;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    Bitmap StoredBitmap;
    Drawable StoredDrawable;
    private static int dataSet = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapDefect=new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
        arrlstCo_ordinate=new ArrayList<String>();
        arrlst_Count=new ArrayList<String>();
        discrepancy_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.number_list);
        discrepancy_list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        objRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);
        objRelativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                String strEditText;
                if(!checkForDataSaved()){
                if(touch){
                    Log.d("ON", "onTouch called");
                    X_CO_ordinate=(int) event.getX() ; 
                    Y_CO_ordinate=(int) event.getY();

                    boolean isNotDuplicate=checkDuplicateElement(X_CO_ordinate,Y_CO_ordinate);
                    if(isNotDuplicate){
                        Log.d("TOUCH", "TOUCH"+X_CO_ordinate+"|"+Y_CO_ordinate+"|"+"Touch :");
                        if(objEditText != null){
                            strEditText=objEditText.getText().toString();
                            Log.d("Err", "EditText not null"+strEditText);

                            if(strEditText != null && strEditText.length() != 0){
//                              if(chekMapEntry(objEditText.getId(), objEditText.getText().toString(), ""+X_CO_ordinate+"|"+Y_CO_ordinate))
//                              {
                                arrlst_Count.add(""+X_CO_ordinate+"|"+Y_CO_ordinate);
                                arrlstCo_ordinate.add(""+X_CO_ordinate+"|"+Y_CO_ordinate);
                                mapDefect.put(objEditText.getId(),objEditText.getText().toString());
                                Log.d("Err", "In Touch Map Size :"+mapDefect.size() +"Arr List Size :"+arrlstCo_ordinate.size());
                                objEditText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                //}else{Toast.makeText(FragmentActivity.this, "Duplicate map entry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                                addEditText();
                                Log.d("Err", "String not null");
                            }else{
                                Log.d("Err", "String null");
                                Toast.makeText(FragmentActivity.this, "Please log the defect ::: in onTouch()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }else{
                            Log.d("Err", "EditText  null");
                            arrlst_Count.add(""+X_CO_ordinate+"|"+Y_CO_ordinate);
                            arrlstCo_ordinate.add(""+X_CO_ordinate+"|"+Y_CO_ordinate);
                            Log.d("Err", "In Touch else Map Size :"+mapDefect.size() +"Arr List Size :"+arrlstCo_ordinate.size());
                            Drawable relative_image_bg = objRelativeLayout.getBackground();
                            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)relative_image_bg).getBitmap();
                            Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_image_screen_new))).getBitmap();

                            if(bitmap.sameAs(bitmap2)){
                                Toast.makeText(FragmentActivity.this, "Please capture the image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(FragmentActivity.this, "Not equal..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                addEditText();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    touch=false;
                }else{
                    touch=true;
                }
            }
                return true;
            }

            private boolean checkDuplicateElement(int x_CO_ordinate,int y_CO_ordinate){
                String strX=String.valueOf(x_CO_ordinate);
                String strY=String.valueOf(y_CO_ordinate);

                for(int i=0;i<arrlstCo_ordinate.size();i++){
                    String strResult=arrlstCo_ordinate.get(i);
                    String []arrResult=StringUtils.split(strResult, "|");
                    String strTemp_X=arrResult[0];
                    String strTemp_Y=arrResult[1];
                    Log.d("CO", ""+strTemp_X+strTemp_Y+"|"+strX+strY);

                    if(strTemp_X.equalsIgnoreCase(strX) || strTemp_Y.equalsIgnoreCase(strY)){
                        Log.d("DUP", "Duplicate element is not allow");
                        Toast.makeText(FragmentActivity.this, "Duplicate element is not allow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        //add list in main.xml

        addList();
        getDefects();


    }

    private void addList(){


        discrepancyList = LocalDatabaseOperations.callDBToGetList(this);

        list_adapter = new DiscrepancyListAdapter(this, discrepancyList);
        discrepancy_list.setAdapter(list_adapter);
        isOnLaunch = true;
        discrepancy_list.performItemClick(null, 0, discrepancy_list.getFirstVisiblePosition());


    }

    private void getDefects(){

        if(LocalDatabaseOperations.callDBToGetDefects(this) == true){
            fechCoordinate();
            addViewEditText();

        }
    }
```

So this is the activity that loads a "list of discrepancies" on the LHS and information about the first item in the list on the RHS of the fragment. But when I go back and come back to this screen, the same acitivty is loaded making it to load the activity. This should happen. However the previous data is also present making the entire data to double.

Comment: `discrepancyList` inisilize inside your addList() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your callDBToGetList() function, I am assuming that you are returning a list(say myList). Make this line as first line of your callDBToGetList() function.

```
myList.clear();
```

Replace myList with the name of list that you are returning.

Comment: There is also another problem with this code:-
On the launch of this activity newly (when the application is first started) the screen is filled with the previous values present in the DB ("the defects"). this is the data that was present fed in the last the app was executed.

Comment: please start this conversation as new question.